# How do I write Junit test case for marshalling and unmarshalling

Tags: java, soap, junit, jaxb

I have the below snippet of code which uses unmarshalling to read the data received from service response. I need to write test cases using junit to test if the code is able to parse both the success and error XML.

Code snippet :

```
ExecuteLegacyAPICallResponse.ExecuteLegacyAPICallResult result = port.executeLegacyAPICall(sessionID,
                    "srtUpdateRealignment", parameters);
            List<Object> resultList = result.getContent();

Iterator<Object> itr = resultList.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                Object o = itr.next();
                LOGGER.info("Object---" + o + " Class----" + o.getClass());

                JAXBContext jaxBContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("webservice.client.wddx");
                Unmarshaller unmarshallerObj = jaxBContext.createUnmarshaller();
                WddxPacket wddxPacket = (WddxPacket) unmarshallerObj.unmarshal((Node) o);

                LOGGER.info("wddxPacket----" + wddxPacket);

                Struct structRealign = (Struct) wddxPacket.getData()
                        .getNullOrBooleanOrNumberOrDateTimeOrStringOrArrayOrStructOrRecordsetOrBinary().get(0);

                LOGGER.info("structRealign----" + structRealign);

                for (Var var : structRealign.getVar()) {
                    if ("return_status".equalsIgnoreCase(var.getName())) {
                        Struct dataStruct = (Struct) var
                                .getNullOrBooleanOrNumberOrDateTimeOrStringOrArrayOrStructOrRecordsetOrBinary().get(0);
                        LOGGER.info("dataStruct return_status----" + dataStruct);
                        isSuccess = isValidStatus(dataStruct);

                        if (!isSuccess) {
                            String errDescription = getStatusDescription(dataStruct);
                            throw new ServiceUnavailableException(errDescription);
                        }
                    }

                    if ("return_data".equalsIgnoreCase(var.getName())) {
                        Struct dataStruct = (Struct) var
                                .getNullOrBooleanOrNumberOrDateTimeOrStringOrArrayOrStructOrRecordsetOrBinary().get(0);
                        for (Var dataVar : dataStruct.getVar()) {
                            LOGGER.info("dataStruct return_data----" + dataStruct);
                            if ("recordset_data".equalsIgnoreCase(dataVar.getName())) {
                                Recordset recordSet = (Recordset) dataVar
                                        .getNullOrBooleanOrNumberOrDateTimeOrStringOrArrayOrStructOrRecordsetOrBinary()
                                        .get(0);
                                LOGGER.info("recordSet ----" + recordSet);
                                for (Field field : recordSet.getField()) {
                                    if ("confirmnum".equalsIgnoreCase(field.getName())) {
                                        List<Object> list = field.getNullOrBooleanOrNumberOrDateTimeOrStringOrBinary();
                                        webservice.client.wddx.String value = (webservice.client.wddx.String) list
                                                .get(0);
                                        confirmNum = value.getvalue();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The class info comes as `org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl`.

How do I convert the sample XML to this object so that my code is able to unmarshall and parse the result?

Sample XML -

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <ExecuteLegacyAPICallResponse xmlns="http://sdda.schwabrt.com/">
         <ExecuteLegacyAPICallResult>
            <wddxPacket version="1.0" xmlns="">
               <header/>
               <data>
                  <struct>
                     <var name="return_status">
                        <struct>
                           <var name="source">
                              <string>SRTPAS_EXE:processRealignment</string>
                           </var>
                           <var name="severity">
                              <string>Error</string>
                           </var>
                           <var name="statuscode">
                              <number>1</number>
                           </var>
                           <var name="statusdesc">
                              <string>Could not convert variant of type (Null) into type (OleStr)</string>
                           </var>
                        </struct>
                     </var>
                     <var name="return_request">
                        <struct>
                           <var name="_tk">
                              <string>www</string>
                           </var>
                           <var name="_rpc">
                              <string>srtUpdateRealignment</string>
                           </var>
                           <var name="_sid">
                              <string>PAS-1E70CCA1CCC54479A620C1DE2D58987A-80</string>
                           </var>
                        </struct>
                     </var>
                  </struct>
               </data>
            </wddxPacket>
         </ExecuteLegacyAPICallResult>
      </ExecuteLegacyAPICallResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Please let me know if any other input is required.

Comment: Isn't it enough to pre-craft an XML document and assert the fields on your `WddxPacket` are populated correctly when deserializing?

Comment: Yes I would assert the fields after deserialization. However I would like to know how do I convert my pre-crafted XML into `org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl` which is returned in the response. I have edited the code snippet which shows that I am receiving an object of `ExecuteLegacyAPICallResponse.ExecuteLegacyAPICallResult` which is having a list of objects.

Comment: Is switching libraries an option here (since JAXB is being removed from the JDK in the latest LTS release)? Just curious, as the solution may be clearer and easier to see with something like Jackson's XML mapper.

Comment: I understand and agree with you. But this is not an option here.